# Why am I getting an Integrity Constraint (parent key not found) when the parent key exists

Tags: sql, oracle, reference, primary-key, referential-integrity

I have a parent record in my people table, but when trying to insert a matching record in my employee table, I get a integrity constraint error. Can anyone explain what is wrong?

[image: People Table Structure]

[image: Employee Table Structure]

[image: Attempted Insert Into Employees]

[image: Foreign Key Creation]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. [mcve]

Comment: "I have a parent record in my people table" - says you, Oracle disagrees. I tend to believe Oracle in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Based on your comment:

> I've added a pic of the foreign keys, personID is present is both the employee table and customer table and references the people table

it seems that you're mistaken.

Oracle doesn't check whether **constraints** exist, but whether **data** (that support those constraints) exist. In other words, first you have to insert a row into a parent table, and then into its child table (whose values "reference" primary key values in the parent table).

The way you posted it, you're inserting into child with no parent.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided images, I can only guess that you are trying to insert a record into "Employee" table with "PersonId" that does not exist in the parent table "People"

If that is not the case, are you able to show us the whole table design including foreign keys?

Comment: I've added a pic of the foreign keys, personID is present is both the employee table and customer table and references the people table.

Comment: @SpaceTurtle84 - do you have a record in "People" table with "PersonID" 5000001?